# BSP Tree construction

Tags: binary-tree

Two objects of seven faces (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) are shown in the figure below. Find a
binary space partitioning tree (BSP tree) that represents the objects (use the left nodes
for those faces in the front and the right nodes for those behind, and choose faces in
the order of a-b-c-d-e-f-g. Split a face if necessary).

[image]

I got a BSP Tree like so from Eye 1 - Blue lines indicate in front while red lines indicate behind. Is this correct?

[image]